# Invalid type for path "sylius_cart.resources.cart.classes.form". Expected array, but got string symfony 2.8.3 sylius 0.17.0

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

this is a pretty clear error message but for some reasons i have been unable to wrap my head around it.

config :

```
sylius_cart:
# The driver used for persistence layer.
driver: ~
# Service id of cart item resolver.
resolver: app.cart_item_resolver
# Cart provider service id.
provider: sylius.cart_provider.default
# The id of cart storage for default provider.
storage: sylius.cart_storage.session
resources:
    cart:
        classes:
            controller: Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Controller\CartController
            form:       Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Form\Type\CartType
        validation_groups:
            default: [ sylius ]
    cart_item:
        classes:
            controller: Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Controller\CartItemController
            form:       Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Form\Type\CartItemType
        validation_groups:
            default: [ sylius ]
```

when I run

> $  php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

i get error:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException]              Invalid type for path "sylius_cart.resources.cart.classes.form". Expected array, but got string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [`Configuration`](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/v0.17.0/src/Sylius/Bundle/CartBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L84-L89) the `sylius_cart.resources.cart.classes.form` expects an array with a single key of `default`.

```
->arrayNode('form')
    ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
    ->children()
        ->scalarNode('default')->defaultValue(CartType::class)->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
    ->end()
->end()
```

You will need to change your config to

```
//...
resources:
    cart:
        classes:
            controller: Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Controller\CartController
            form:
                default: Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Form\Type\CartType
        validation_groups:
            default: [ sylius ]
    cart_item:
        classes:
            controller: Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Controller\CartItemController
            form:
                default: Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Form\Type\CartItemType
        validation_groups:
            default: [ sylius ]
```